# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" but I'm not sure why

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure why but when I try to click on anything in `local:3000` it goes to the error page and says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

```
  const listLocations = locations.map((place, id) => {
  console.log(place.name);
  return (
    <p key={place.id} onClick={() => showLocation(place)}>{place.name}</p>
  );
});

  const showLocation = (place) => {
    if (this.state[place.id] === 'hidden') {
      this.setState(this.defaultState);
      this.setState({ [place.id]: '', currentLocation: place });
  }   else {
      this.setState({ [place.id]: 'hidden', currentLocation: {} });
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide more clarity as to what `local:3000` is?

Comment: He probably meant localhost:3000.  Is this code inside a functional component or a class component?  Can you show the whole component, and where this code is relative to that?  Sounds like you're either trying to call `this.state` on a functional component, or you've brought your functions outside the component body where `this` is no longer the component instance.

Comment: can you add more code of the whole component?

Comment: maybe you are using  ```this``` in a Functional Component

Comment: @SethLutske he has other question with same code where it seems he is converting a class component to hooks. so yes, he is likely using `this` using it incorrectly here.

Comment: You have to use `useState` hook for functional component.

Comment: @SethLutske Im not exactly sure how to show all that on here I just signed up like an hour ago, wish i could just share the whole app.js code

Comment: @loboxguts Codesandbox.io

Comment: @codemonkey https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-pine-pt92c?file=/src/App.js somewhere around line 31-38 is the issue

Comment: please also import your `./locations` file. It's missing from the sandbox

Comment: @codemonkey here i uploaded the all the files https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-fog-irgq4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is this class component or functional component??

Comment: @rijo rajan its suppose to be a functional but im not sure how to write it out as one

Comment: @loboxguts FC not like above code as you posted. Its combination of class component and FC. Can you post a full code I will covert to FC.For more about FC see this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html  and also know about setting state in class component see this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly